# C Concatenate Operator vs + Operator

Tags: c, algorithm, operators, concatenation

i want to use concatenation as an math operator-keyword just like that

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 void main() {
     int a = 15;
     int b = 15;
     char var = '+';

     printf("result: %d", (a, var, b));

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: And I want ten million dollars. Or twenty..

Comment: That's not how C works. A string containing an operator does not act like the operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(char **argv, int argc) {
   int a = 15;
   int b = 15;
   char var = '+';
   if (var == '+') { // Check to see if it is a '+' and then add if so
      printf("result: %d\n", a + b); // the \n prints a newline
   }
   return 0;
}
```

for each operator. You may consider using something like `flex` to parse tokens.

Comment: Why the downvotes on this answer? And why on the question? Haven't we all been here once?

Comment: Milliennium Bug look, the problem is that i want to get two numbers and the operations wanted (as character '+' or '-'..etc) then i need to make the calcul WITHOUT USING CONDITIONS ON THE OPERATION

Comment: just like that:
#include <stdio.h>
void main(char **argv, int argc) {
   int a = 15;
   int b = 5;
   char var = '+'; //this is the operation as a character 
  
      printf("result: %d\n", ??);  
   }
   return 0;
}

Comment: It cannot be done in C with the standard library; This is how it would be implemented (except 100's of lines more) in the standard library.

Comment: what about algorithms? can you provide and algorithm who can do that? thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, was answering another question. This IS an algorithm, and most likely the only type of algorithm (besides JS eval) that could do this. You could use JavaScript eval, but you are using C. JavaScript eval is implementation-dependent and way too complex for this type of code.

Answer (score 0):

How about getting some help from the shell:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 int main(void) {
     char buf[80];
     int a = 15;
     int b = 15;
     char var = '+';

     snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "echo $[%d%c%d]", a, var, b); 
     return system(buf);
 }
```

It works on unix and OS/X. I don't know about Windows, but I hear they ship bash nowadays. Many operators supported: `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`, `^`, `|`, `&` and also `,`, `<` and `>`.